# I am trying to create an Image Slider, but when I set the position of the angle left icon to ABSOLUTE, it disappears from the screen

Tags: html, css

The angle left icon basically disappears when I set its position to absolute, but it remains otherwise.

Here the angle left icon is not visible due its position property. How can it appear on the screen so that I can position it on the top left part of the image, so as to make an image slider.

This is my html code:

```
<section>
            <div class="team">
                <div>
                    <h1 id="teamtext">Our Team and Contributers</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="imageslider">
                        <img src="assets/photo1.jpg">
                        <img src="assets/photo2.jpg">
                        <img src="assets/photo3.jpg">
                        <img src="assets/photo4.jpg">
                        <img src="assets/photo5.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideleft">
                    <i class="uil uil-angle-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="slideright">
                    <i class="uil uil-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
.content{
    height: 400px;
    width: 750px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imageslider{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
}

.imageslider img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.slideleft{
    color: red;
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.slideright{
    color: red;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

I searched similar questions in the internet but they aren't working.

Comment: Try using a snippet (Ctrl+M) to increase the understanding of your question. If you can reproduce the problem here, it will be easier for someone to understand and propose a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears while having `position: absolute;`. Please see my codesnippet:

```css
<style type="text/css">.content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 750px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid;
}

.imageslider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.imageslider img {
  width: 50%;
  height: calc(400px / 3);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slideleft {
  color: red;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
}

.slideright {
  color: red;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="team">
    <div>
      <h1 id="teamtext">Our Team and Contributers</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="imageslider">
        <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
        <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
        <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
        <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
        <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideleft">
      <i class="uil uil-angle-left">slideleft</i>
    </div>
    <div class="slideright">
      <i class="uil uil-angle-right">slideright</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```